# Why A.class.getClassLoader() does not return the loader used by loader.loadClass("A")

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

In this test case we are loading a class `A` through a specific class loader instance, i.e. `GwClassLoader`. However, the `A.class.getClassLoader()` does not retrieve that class loader? This is the test case:

```
class A{
  static {
    ClassLoader loader = A.class.getClassLoader();
    System.out.println("A.<cinit>: " + loader);
  }
}

class ClassLoaderGw extends ClassLoader { }

public class App {
  public static void main(String [] args)  throws ClassNotFoundException,  InstantiationException,  IllegalAccessException {
    ClassLoaderGw loader = new ClassLoaderGw();
    System.out.println("Main: " + loader);
    Class<?> klass = loader.loadClass("A");
    Object obj = klass.newInstance();
  }
}
```

And, this is the output of running the class `App`:

```
Main: ClassLoaderGw@6d06d69c
A.<cinit>: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
```

How can I get the instance of `GwClassLoader` inside the static constructor of the class `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClassLoaderGw` simply extends `ClassLoader` without overriding any methods.  Therefore, it will follow the strategy of the standard `loadClass` method ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-boolean-)) ... which is to delegate to the parent classloader first.

In this case, your `A` class is on the parent classloader's classpath, so *that* is what will load it.

The final piece of the puzzle is that `getClassLoader()` returns the classloader that *actually* loaded the class, not the classloader that you asked to do the loading.

---

> How can I get the instance of GwClassLoader inside the static constructor of the class A?

Basically, you can't ... unless `GwClassloader` was responsible for loading the class `A`.

Could you *make* it work?  Well ... if you used a different class loading strategy you could.  Maybe.  If `GwClassloader` was able to find the bytecodes for `A` and call `defineClass` itself, then it would be the classloader for `A`.

However, you need to worry about the possibility that class `A` could also be loaded by the parent classloader.  If that happens you could have two distinct `A` types in existence at the same time.  This can lead to class cast exceptions in unexpected places.

Comment: Solved. By invoking `defineClass`, then it would be the `classloader` for intended class. Here it is the new implementation for [`ClassLoaderGw`](https://gist.github.com/fmcarvalho/1fecd5310f74c1153154886202a1e133#file-classloadergw-java)

Answer (score 1):

This is described in [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-boolean-):

> Loads the class with the specified binary name. The default implementation of this method searches for classes in the following order:
>
> - Invoke findLoadedClass(String) to check if the class has already been loaded.
> - **Invoke the loadClass method on the parent class loader**. If the parent is null the class loader built-in to the virtual machine is used, instead.
> - Invoke the findClass(String) method to find the class.

Your `ClassLoader` has the `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader1` as a parent, because as described in the Javadoc of the [default constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#ClassLoader--) (which is implicitly invoked in the `ClassLoaderGw` class, because there is no explicit constructor):

> Creates a new class loader using the ClassLoader returned by the method getSystemClassLoader() as the parent class loader.